# parse json data from curl

Tags: php, json, curl

`server.php`

```php
// some code here ..... 
// this is the end of the file:

$json_data = array(
    'test1'=>hello world,
    'test2'=>hello stack
);

echo json_encode($json_data);
```

`api.php`

```php
$text = api("http://example.com/?TEXT=$text&APIKEY=$apikey");
// return the json from server.php file
echo $text;

function api($url) {
     $ch = curl_init();
     $timeout = 20;
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
     $data = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);
     return $data;
}
```

the file `api.php` return the json successfully

```json
{"test1":"hello world","test2":"hello stack"}
```

The problem is when I try to parse the returned JSON in order to get the value of `test1` it doesn't show anything.

I tried something like this it but can't parse the JSON.

```php
$obj=json_decode($text);
// dosent show anything
echo $obj->test1;
```

Comment: Can you please run `var_dump($text, $obj, json_last_error())` and post its output into the question?

Comment: i tried but it shows a blank page *_*

Comment: I guess you're using one of those PHP bundles that hide errors by default. You should find the `php.ini` file and tweak error related directives.

Answer (score 1):

Put quotes around the values in your array.

```
   $json_data = array(

    'test1'=>"hello world",
    'test2'=>"hello stack");
```